# Login without asked for credentials on two enviorments

Tags: .net, cookies, model-view-controller

I have this asp.net MVC application, I use cookie authentication with UseCookieAuthentication, but when application is accessed from test and production Environments on same browser, I am able to enter in the second Environment without been asked for password and username, and I am already authenticated. They use different databases so the usernames and password for both are different

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                CookieHttpOnly = true,
                //SlidingExpiration = true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationProvider(),
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,             
                CookieSecure = Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest
            });
```

How I am able to ask for credentials based on domain - if user of this domain is not logged ask for credentials

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I edited: I want to be asked for credentials on both enviorments

Answer (score 0):

```
try to add cookie domain property.

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                CookieDomain="domain.com",
                AuthenticationType = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                CookieHttpOnly = true,
                //SlidingExpiration = true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationProvider(),
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,             
                CookieSecure = Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest
            });
```

and check what will happen.